# Load different grayscale images into the same texture

Tags: opengl, textures, image

I have a series of images loaded as

```
data1 = stbi_load_from_file(file1,&width,&height,&comp,1); 
data2 = stbi_load_from_file(file2,&width,&height,&comp,1); 
data3 = stbi_load_from_file(file3,&width,&height,&comp,1);
```

So that they're grayscale images. I then want to load these three images into a single `GL_RGB` texture. How can I do this? Do I have to allocate new memory and create a new image picking the channels info from the three different images?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to swizzle the data into the desired format, like GL_RGB, with a nice for-loop. :-) then glTexImage2D().

Comment: @davidvanbrink, I thought that was the only way! Thank you!